# How to call one view for two different controllers and redirect them according to the controller in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I would like to redirect the form submission according to the controller wise

```
    function list_mapdemand($id)
{
    $data['titlte'] = "mapdemand";
    $data['demand_id']  = $id;  
    $data['get_map_demand'] =   $this->demands_model->get_exist_demand_map_from_prospect($id);
    //print_r($data['get_map_demand']);
    //exit;
    //print_r($data['get_map_candidate']);
    $data['get_mapped_demand'] =    $this->demands_model->get_exist_prospective_candidate($id);
    $data['demand_results'] =  $this->demands_model->get_demand_details($id); 
    $data['candidates'] = $this->demands_model->get_candidates($id, $data['get_map_demand']);
    //print_r($data['candidates'])  ;
    $this->load->view("list_map_demand_to_candidate",$data);
}


 function list_search_mapdemand($id)
{
    $data['titlte'] = "mapdemand";
    $data['demand_id']  = $id;  
    $data['get_map_demand'] =   $this->demands_model->get_exist_demand_map_from_prospect($id);
    //print_r($data['get_map_demand']);
    //print_r($data['get_map_candidate']);
    $data['get_mapped_demand'] =    $this->demands_model->get_exist_prospective_candidate($id);
    $data['demand_results'] =  $this->demands_model->get_demand_details($id); 
    $data['candidates'] = $this->demands_model->get_candidates($id, $data['get_map_demand']);
    //print_r($data['candidates'])  ;
    $this->load->view("list_map_demand_to_candidate",$data);
}
```

One controller will be used in search list and another one is for normal list. I have to redirect the page acccording to the controller wise but one view page must control. For ADD, EDIT, VIEW. After add it must go to the controller mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could do some thing like this `<form action="<?php echo $action;?>"` and something like on controller below.

```
public function edit() {
// plus form validation or what ever you want
$this->getForm();
}

public function add() {
 // plus form validation or what ever you want
 $this->getForm();
}

public function getForm() {

// Make sure your uri segment correct uri segment 4 for me is id.

// http://localhost/codeigniter/project/admin/website/edit/54

// http://localhost/codeigniter/project/admin/website/add

  if ($this->uri->segment(4) === FALSE) {
    $data['action'] = site_url('admin/website/add');
  } else {
    $data['action'] = site_url('admin/website/edit/' . $this->uri->segment(4));
  }

  return $this->load->view(folder/file, $data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add this to your functions. like at your list_mapdemand function

```
$data['link']="YOUR_SUBMIT_LINK_FROM_list_mapdemand_FUNTION";
```

and at your list_search_mapdemand function add

```
$data['link']="YOUR_SUBMIT_LINK_FROM_list_search_mapdemand_FUNTION";
```

now use $link at your view from tag

```
<from ... action="<?php echo $link; ?>....>
```